# /etc/network/interfaces no such file or directory

Tags: virtual-machine, centos6, vmware-workstation

I have installed centOS 6.6 on VMWare workstation 11, and I was not able to connect to the internet, so I have followed this article [centos-minimal-installation](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/centos-minimal-installation) to configure the network, but then I end up with an error that there is no

> /etc/network/interfaces no such file or directory

I have read many article and blog but I never come across anything that could solve my problem so that I can connect to internet. Kindly assist me.

Answer (score 2):

Need more info to even start guessing but "/etc/network/interfaces" hints that you trying debian stuff on centos and that's not going to work.
That blog does not talk about /etc/network/interfaces so it's not from there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I reinstalled the centos, and it fixed, dont know why there was issue.